# What's the meaning of "ran for"

Tags: phrases

I'm reading a Aesop's fable, [The Kingdom of the Lion](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/35/aesops-fables/624/the-kingdom-of-the-lion/). I cannot understand the last sentence in the fable:

> And after the Hare said this, he ran for his life.

What's the meaning of the phrase "ran for"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Run for" is not the applicable phrase. The parsing is *[run] [for his life]*, that is, the Hare ran as if his life depended on it.

Comment: While "run as if to save one's life" is a common meaning of the phrase, in the instance the OP's asking about it seems to mean "run to save one's life", as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the Hare ran to save his life (apparently his life was in danger).

Comment: Do you mean that the Hare just ran away to avoid to be eaten?

Comment: @CookSchelling: That's exactly the meaning.

Comment: Think of it as "the hare ran [for the sake of] his life."